# can we combine php server pages in a rails application?

Tags: php, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way so that we can combine PHP pages in ruby on rails application?

Comment: Define "combine"

Comment: very vague, you might wanna update your question with more details

Answer (score 2):

You can run them on the same webserver if you use apache. They are able to share the same database. One thing you won't be able to do is sharing data directly amongst them, for that an API to communicate between the apps will be required.